# No. of solutions to a integer-based inequality

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, inequality, integers

- Let $p, q$ be positive integers such that $q≤99$. Find number of ordered pairs $(p,q)$ such that $$\frac {2}{5} \ < \frac {p}{q} \ < \ \frac {21}{50}. $$

Here's what I could do:
Using the fact that if  $ 0 \ < \frac {a}{b} < 1  \ \Rightarrow  \frac {a}{b}  \ < \  \frac {a+d}{b+d} $
where $d>0, $   I could find a few solutions like $(p,q) \ = (41,99) \ (40,98) \, (39,96), \ etc. $ But it seems like there are a lot more possible solution pairs.

What should be a proper strategy?

Any hint or help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I mean that. Edited

Comment: Please include that information in the question.

Comment: What are ordered pairs? E.g. $p=20 , q\in\left\{48,49\right\}$ do you accept these pairs?

Comment: @lonestudent Yes, you are right

Comment: Are you writing software?  Or doing a contest?

Comment: @DanielV I am doing a contest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\frac {2}{5} \ < \frac {p}{q} \ < \ \frac {21}{50}
\implies
 \frac{20q}{50} \lt p\lt \frac {21q}{50}\\ \\
\end{align*}

This means
$\space \dfrac{20\cdot12}{50}=4.8 \lt p\le 
\bigg\lfloor\dfrac{21q}{50}-0.01\bigg\rfloor=41.58-0.01,  q=99\space$
and

when $\space0<\bigg\lfloor\dfrac{21q}{50}-0.01\bigg\rfloor- \dfrac{20q}{50}<1\space$
there is one pair

when $\space 1<\bigg\lfloor\dfrac{21q}{50}-0.01\bigg\rfloor- \dfrac{20q}{50}<2\space$ there are two pairs.

There is a single pair for $49\space q$-values and
two pairs for $20\space q$-values. A spreadsheet shows these $89$ solutions as

\begin{align*}
(5,12)\quad 
(7,17)\quad 
(9,22)\quad 
(10,24)\quad 
(11,27)\quad 
(12,29)\\ 
(13,31)\quad 
(13,32)\quad 
(14,34)\quad 
(15,36)\quad 
(15,37)\quad 
(16,39)\\ 
(17,41)\quad 
(17,42)\quad 
(18,43)\quad 
(18,44)\quad 
(19,46)\quad 
(19,47)\\ 
(20,48)\quad 
(20,49)\quad 
(21,51)\quad 
(21,52)\quad 
(22,53)\quad 
(22,54)\\ 
(23,55)\quad 
(23,56)\quad 
(23,57)\quad 
(24,58)\quad 
(24,59)\quad 
(25,60)\\ 
(25,61)\quad 
(25,62)\quad (26,62)\quad 
(26,63)\quad 
(26,64)\quad 
(27,65)\\ 
(27,66)\quad 
(27,67)\quad (28,67)\quad 
(28,68)\quad 
(28,69)\quad 
(29,70)\\ 
(29,71)\quad 
(29,72)\quad (30,72)\quad 
(30,73)\quad 
(30,74)\quad (31,74)\\ 
(31,75)\quad 
(31,76)\quad 
(31,77)\quad (32,77)\quad 
(32,78)\quad 
(32,79)\\ (33,79)\quad 
(33,80)\quad 
(33,81)\quad (34,81)\quad 
(33,82)\quad (34,82)\\ 
(34,83)\quad 
(34,84)\quad (35,84)\quad 
(35,85)\quad 
(35,86)\quad (36,86)\\ 
(35,87)\quad (36,87)\quad 
(36,88)\quad 
(36,89)\quad (37,89)\quad 
(37,90)\\ 
(37,91)\quad (38,91)\quad 
(37,92)\quad (38,92)\quad 
(38,93)\quad (39,93)\\ 
(38,94)\quad (39,94)\quad 
(39,95)\quad 
(39,96)\quad (40,96)\quad 
(39,97)\\ (40,97)\quad 
(40,98)\quad (41,98)\quad 
(40,99)\quad (41,99)\\ 
\end{align*}

Comment: Are you referring to the floor function?

Comment: Sorry, but could you please elaborate how $0.01$ came?

Comment: Yes I am referring to the floor function. The alternative was $INT()$. As for the $0.01$, it could have been $0.0000001$ or anything smaller than $0.01$ just to make $p$ be  smaller than the high limit.

Comment: @poetasis:  You seem to be using the condition $q > 12$ *without proof*.

Comment: @Arnie Bebita-Dris
 Yes I did use $\space q >12\space$ without proof but no proof was requested. Perhaps I could have shown that 
$\space\dfrac{20\cdot 13}{50}=5.2\not\lt p\space
 \le 
\bigg\lfloor\dfrac{21\cdot 13}{50}-0.01\bigg\rfloor=\big\lfloor5.46-0.01\big\rfloor,\space  q=13\space$
but I do not know what else. I'm an amateur about  $45$ years removed from academia but I'm willing to learn if you can suggest a better treatment.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  $q \leq 99$ and
$$\frac{p}{q} < \frac{21}{50}$$
with $q$ positive imply that
$$p < \frac{21q}{50} \leq \frac{21 \cdot 99}{50} = 41.58$$
which further means that
$$p \leq 41.$$

**Can you finish?**

Comment: May I know why this answer was downvoted?

Comment: this is something which I could find as well, can we somehow find lower limit for p or q?

Comment: In particular, this answer shows that the number of solutions to the problem is *finite*, and may thus be determined via *brute force*.

Comment: ohk . thanks for your efforts

Comment: Sure,
$$\frac{2}{5} < \frac{p}{q} \implies p > \frac{2q}{5} \geq \frac{2}{5},$$
since $q > 0$ implies $q \geq 1$, so that the best lower bound that you will be able to find for $p$ and $q$ are
$$p \geq 1$$
and
$$q \geq 1.$$

Answer (score 1):

After rearranging you can see that $\dfrac{2q}{5} < p < \dfrac{21q}{50}$
so there must be an integer between

$\dfrac{2q}{5}$ and $\dfrac{21q}{50}$and also their difference $= \dfrac{q}{50} < 2$ so their can't be more than 2 integers.

So solve the equations $$ \begin{align} 
\left\lfloor\dfrac{21q}{50} \right\rfloor - \left\lfloor\dfrac{2q}{5}  \right\rfloor &= 1\\
\left\lfloor\dfrac{21q}{50} \right\rfloor - \left\lfloor\dfrac{2q}{5}  \right\rfloor &= 2 \end{align} $$

And then you multiply by the 2 the number of solutions to the second and add that to the first

Comment: I got the idea, thanks

Comment: thanks @AbVk1718

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach.

$$Z=\sum_p\sum_{1 \le q < 100} [2/5 < p/q < 21/50]$$

can be rewritten as

$$Z=\left(\sum_p\sum_{1 \le q < 100} [p < 21q/50]\right) - \left(\sum_p\sum_{1 \le q < 100} [p \le 2q/5]\right)$$

And $p < 21q/50$ is the same as $p \le 21q/50$ except when $50|q$, so both sums are effectively the same problem.

So generalizing (and assuming s,t coprime):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
f(s, t, n) 
&=& \sum_{0 \le q < nt} \sum_p[p \le sq/t]
\\ &=& \sum_{0 \le q < nt} \lfloor sq/t \rfloor + 1
\\ &=& nt + \sum_{0 \le r < t} \sum_{0 \le q < n} \lfloor s(qt + r)/t \rfloor
\\ &=& nt + \sum_{0 \le r < t} \sum_{0 \le q < n} sq + \lfloor sr/t \rfloor 
\\ &=& nt + st\frac{n^2-n}{2} + n\sum_{0 \le r < t} \lfloor sr/t \rfloor 
\\ &=& nt + st\frac{n^2-n}{2} + n\sum_{0 \le r < t} \frac{sr - (sr \mod t)}{t}
\\ &=& nt + st\frac{n^2-n}{2} + \frac{n}{t}(s\frac{t^2-t}{2} - \frac{t^2-t}{2})
\\ &=& \frac n2 (nst + t - s + 1)
\end{array}$$

That for s,t coprime $$(\sum_{0 \le r < t} {sr \mod t}) = (t^2 - t)/2$$ is exploiting the neat property that for the function $g(r) = (sr \mod t)$, the image of ${0 .. t-1}$ is exactly ${0 .. t-1}$, that is, it is a permutation.

The lowerbound for the Z sums isn't $0\le q$, it's $1 \le q$; so we need to subtract the $q=0$ term from the sums.  So the solution is

$$Z = f(21, 50, 2) - f(2, 5, 20) - \underbrace{100/50}_\text{(a)} - \underbrace{(0 - 1)}_\text{(b)} = 89$$

(a) Correction for the $50|q$ terms in the first sum

(b) Correction for the $q=0$ case in both sums